# Python 3.6.5 - Matplotlib.pyplot.hist - To many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.6, valueerror

I'm trying to execute this code into a Jupyter-Notebook :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = 20 * np.random.randn(10000)

plt.hist(x, 25, range=(-50, 50), histtype='stepfilled',
         align='mid', color='g', label='Données de test')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Histogramme avec remplissage')
plt.show()
```

I have an error during the histogram processing :

- It deals with everything until the error shows up with "stacked=stacked, normed=normed, data=data, **kwargs"
  Then it says it activated "RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2"
  The error that occurred is ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Do you have any idea of what I could do to solve this problem and finally make my code right ?

I got this example from the book *Python pour la Datascience pour les Nuls*, normally it has to work with Python 3.6.5.
Some examples showed in the book are not working with current python version, which is why I'm using 3.6

In advance, thanks for your help !

Lemisourd

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. The code runs without issue in my environment in Jupyter. If you're in anaconda, at the anaconda prompt `conda update --all`, otherwise update with `pip`.

Comment: I'm using it from conda's environment, I updated it as you advised me, but it's still giving me the same answer. Are you using python3.6 to test this code ?

Comment: I retried but in a python 3.8 environment, and it worked. I tested some things with pyplot.hist parameters, and it shows that the parameter normed as been replaced by density in the library, maybe it as something to do with my issues.

Comment: Make sure you activated the correct environment to update